# Do I need definite article here: "‘Vars’ is a list in which global and local variables are added and updated."

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

I wrote:

> ‘***Vars***’ is **a list** in which global and local variables are added and updated.

I am describing an algorithm in which *Vars* is the name of a list (a variable of type list). There is just one list in this algorithm, then I don't know if I should say *...is a list* or *...is **the** list*.

Is it possible when I say *...is a list*, the reader thinks it is just one instance of many lists and that is not unique? Or  are these unrelated to the  indefinite article? However, if we suppose many copies of this algorithm, or many running of this algorithm, we have a *Vars* for each of them, but  I  don't describe that context.

Comment: Here is a thought provoking example. I believe that you wouldn't be surprised to read, say, in a novel, *Jim is a man who ...*, even though there is only one Jim and only one such man as described in the *who*-clause in the story. *Jim is the man who ...* is also possible. One possible way to solve your hesitation before choosing *a* or *the* in your sentence (I assume that your sentence is just a mockup, not a real sentence in your article) is to see if your sentence is more like *Jim is a man who ...* or *Jim is the man who ...*

Comment: @damkerngt. You could bring complete sentences.

Comment: I thought it'd be easy to find, e.g., *Qati was a man who had never lost touch with the fundamentals* and *Bush was the man who collected that particular political pot* (both clauses are in the same novel). Or, let's take an example from my recent code: *Each segment can be thought of as a linked list, which can be walked through starting from Segment.lastPixel*, and *Segments is a global array that keeps all linked-list segments*. If I were to rephrase the 2nd sentence with *the*, it may go like *Segments is the global array holding all linked-list segments in this implementation.*

Answer (score 3):

To say that "X is *a* list" identifies the kind of thing X is.

To say that "X is *the* list that contains {something}" or "in which {something} is stored"

identifies X as either:

a) the *only* list that contains {something} or in which {something} is stored
b) the *aforementioned* list, which contains {something} or in which {something} is stored

If, *in the context of your algorithm*, X is a "singleton" (the only instance), then you would use "the".

I don't know why you would want to discuss a situation where there were many instances of the context, your algorithm. When describing how an algorithm works, you need not complicate things by envisioning a situation where it is running on many different computers all around the world (unless it were a peer-to-peer algorithm that talks to other instances of itself). But let's say it was analogous to this scenario:

This is the basket for storing tomatoes. (the one and only)

This is the basket for storing apples.  (the one and only)

and many households all around the world also had two baskets, one for tomatoes, one for apples. Then you could speak of "*the baskets* for storing apples" when your context is all the households in the world. There is not one, and only one, such basket in the entire world. **The**, there, would either differentiate the apple baskets from the tomato baskets, or would be used as *the aforementioned baskets*. But when the context becomes each household, there is one, and only one, such basket for storing apples.
Basket : household :: list : algorithm

Comment: In *I'll stop at the garage to fill **the** tank* it's always the definite article because the speaker is referencing the one and only tank in ***his*** car, regardless of the fact that other cars have other tanks. But although *I'll stop at the garage to fill **the** spare fuel can* is more likely, it would be okay to say ***a** can* there (regardless of whether other cars also contain spare fuel cans, or whether the speaker himself has more than one such can).

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not implying that **a** could not be used with the spare fuel can. **a** says what kind of thing it is.  I'm talking about what the meaning of **the** is.

Comment: I think @Fumble is saying that the use of _the_ doesn't necessarily mean there is "only one" of something; it could mean there is only one of something _that we care about_. For example, I might say, "I'm gonna go sit in the chair," but that doesn't necessarily mean there's one and only one chair in whatever room I happen to be in.

Comment: Sure I don't want to speak about the context of all the computers running this algorithm.... I just mentioned that to know if this fact has any relation or any affect, and you say *No*, because I am speaking about the context of the drawn algorithm. (I got that).

Comment: Then you mean when we use *a* it shows it is of the type list and has no contradiction with being known, specific, aforementioned, unique etc? Now, I think I should better use **the** for the reasons above, but yet can use **a** right? that way, just I am saying it is of type list.

Comment: @Ahmad. **a** identifies what kind of thing it is.  A gas can.  A list.  However, in contexts where the listener/reader is expecting to be informed whenever there is only one of something (as a singleton in an algorithm), then to use **a** with a singleton could be confusing.  The listener/reader could infer that there is more than one instance of the thing, when in fact there is not.

Comment: @J.R. But it does mean that you have a specific chair in mind. It is the one and only chair in that sense: the one you're intending to sit in. If you're going to try several out, then you'd say "a chair".

Comment: @Ahmad:  But you could easily say "For this purpose we are using **a** Bag, since the order of the items is unimportant.  **The** Variables Bag stores all of the variables...."  First you identify what kind of thing it is and then you indicate, with **the**, that there is only one.

Comment: @tromano each variable in a program is unique with a unique name. I don't get what you mean by singleton. In object oriented programing a singleton class or type is one which only has one instance. But that dosn't apply to variables.

Comment: An example. He is the player l like. He is a football player. Or this is the car l like. This is a car. In my sentence I point to a specific list and don't care it is yet a list.

Comment: @Ahmad, TRomano: Suppose when you were taking your frail grandmother round an art gallery, she suddenly felt faint. Even if there was only *one* chair in the immediate vicinity, you could still quite reasonably say *Why don't you sit on **a** chair for a moment?* (though you could use ***the*** if you were gesturing towards it, and/or granny could obviously see it clearly herself).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You keep bringing up opportunities to use **a** but I am not interested in **a** as I am trying to answer OP's question, under what circumstances he should use **the**.

Comment: @Ahmad: I am not talking about variables but about the list. Is there, or is there not, more than one **list** of variables?

Comment: You say there is one. So what I would say: "All global and local variables are kept in a single variables list.  The variables list is named Vars."

Comment: @tromano there is one list and there is one such a list for this purpose . And in previous section I talked about the usage of variables. In the  algorithm I store them in a list

Comment: @TRomano: I think in OP's exact context it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to use ***a*** or ***the***. The thrust of my first comment was perhaps better set out by J.R., but my second comment was primarily directed at OP to show that there are plenty of other contexts where it makes little or no difference which article is used, or where ***the*** doesn't necessarily imply there are no others - which doesn't matter if the one we mean is (at least, *potentially*) contextually identifiable.

Comment: @tromano the line is part of the pseudocode of algorithm for declaration of Vars

Comment: @Ahmad:  If  it is helpful for your reader to know that there is only one such list containing the variables, use "the", and do your best to let the reader know in other ways as well, not relying solely upon the choice of article to convey this information. As I said, "All variables are stored in *a single list* called <listname>.   The <listname> list etc etc etc..."

Comment: Thanks I use "the". I just said l can't write it as you suggest. It is one line description in a pseudocode begining with the name of the variable

Comment: @Ahmad: Where did you say that you were restricted to a certain number of words and that you were limited in what you could say?

Comment: @TRomano The same time I commented about the restriction I modified my question too! sorry, I maybe should have said it in the first place, but couldn't predict it is important too.

Comment: @TRomano sorry, I modified my question again! right, I have no restriction for that sentence and that is inside the article, for pseudo code I wrote ***Vars**, the list of global and local variables, initially empty!*

Comment: @Ahmad: That is very clear, and "..., initially empty" is very good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you yourself say

> I am describing **an** algorithm in which *Vars* is the name of a list.

You are introducing a unique algorithm to the reader. It is so unique that you can refer back to it with the demonstrative pronoun *this* in

> There is just one list in *this* algorithm

and everyone knows *which algorithm* you are referring to, namely the one you just introduced to us.

By using *an algorithm* you are not  implying  that there are  other algorithms in which Vars is a list.  Likewise,    the reader is not going to assume that there are other such algorithms in which Vars is a list.

The same goes for the indefinite noun phrase *a list* in the sentence you ask about.

Comment: Right, it seems indefinite article has no relation with the uniqueness or the number of a thing. I don't know why I forgot that, it seems its  main application is to specify the type of something like John is a man, this is a car...

Comment: Both  native and non-native speakers often forget or  do not realize  that an indefinite noun phrase can  make a specific reference: 'I married *a woman* from Japan'  talks about a specific ("unique")  woman.